# Installing the latest kernel

Tags: kernel, 16.04, dpkg

Which deb files(http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7-rc6-yakkety/) are relevant for 64-bit install. The instructions mention not every 64 filename should be installed(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

- the ones that have `generic` NOT `low latency` in the name and
- the ones that have `amd64` NOT `arm64` AND
- the one that ends with 'all'.

That should give you 3 in total:

- `linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic_4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332_amd64.deb`
- `linux-headers-4.7.0-040700rc6_4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332_all.deb`
- `linux-image-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic_4.7.0-040700rc6.201607040332_amd64.deb`

---

To uninstall you just have to remove everything relating to that kernel so, assuming you want to remove the kernel linux-image-4.7.0-040700rc6-generic the standard method is:

Boot a different kernel by selecting an older one from GRUB menu: 'Advanced Options for Ubuntu'

*Check* you booted a different kernel with `uname -r` - **do not delete the running kernel**

Find installed packages relating to the kernel using the name string:

```
dpkg -l | grep 4.7.0-040700rc6
```

remove all the listed packages with their names (replace with actual names):

```
sudo apt-get remove name-of-package1 name-of-package2
dpkg --purge name-of-package1 name-of-package2
```

run `sudo update-grub` to clean the boot menu

---

I prefer to use the `locate` command to remove upstream kernels, because I'm lazy. After booting a different kernel & checking with `uname -r` do (replace with the name string of the kernel you want to remove):

```
sudo updatedb
locate -b -e 4.7.0-040700rc6 | xargs -p sudo rm -r
sudo update-grub
```

You get an error for files that are not directories (because it's trying to remove them recursively), but it still works, and it cleans everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The kernel ppa is not maintained anymore. Now the only way is to download and install the image.deb package manually from below url or build kernel for yourself.
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

> You can add kernel-ppa to repo:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then install the linux kernel pacakges you want to.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-image-xxx
> ```